# CSS Side Effects of Googles Blink Engine

Tags: css, google-chrome

today I took a closer look at my website and recognized the some elements were displayed at a wrong position.

After some searching I noticed that my Chrome was in version 30... beta. With this Update the Blink engine also comes along.

Now my question is if someone knows were I can find a complete changelog or if someone has the same problem and is working on it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The Blink engine was actually first included with Chrome 28.

Comment: Ok, but I'm not on the wrong way with my suspicion that these side effects are caused by Blink, or am I?

Comment: Try searching here : http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.nl/